# AWS Auto scaling drops ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

The thing is I have an ec2 instance with some public key inside **~/.ssh/authorized_keys** to let developers ssh into this instance, but one day the autoscaling mechanism create a new instance and then drop my old instance(with authorized keys inside), and now I gotta edit the **~/.ssh/authorized_keys** in the new instance again.

How can I prevent this? I mean how can I make sure whenever the autoscaling creating a new instance or dropping my old instance, it sync all of my authorized_keys, so that I don't need to do the manual copying.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the AMI id which you have specified in the auto scaling contains old data. Create an AMI of your latest and update instance and remove the old AMI which you have already specified in the as-config and the add the latest AMI id. Thing will work fine.